# iOS UIWebView does not detect javascript when browsing a about:blank url

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, web-applications, uiwebview

In my iOS app for iPhone and iPad I have a UIWebView where I show my web application. In my web application I have a link/button which opens a new window (window.open). This new window does not have an url. In this window I have some JavaScript and Jquery but it does not work in `UIWebView`. It works fine in safari and androids devices. I am coding in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

If your target is iOS 8 and upper, try using WKWebView. Maybe you need to use the WKWebView controller's delegate to make sure that everything is loaded before the JS code is executed.

Example code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class AboutViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.yoursite.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        view = webView
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // the page begins to load... do what you want here (maybe an indicator to say it is loading...)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // the page is done loading. do what you need here
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank for your respons. I tried to use WKWebView but same problem. Which delegate should I use. Can you please come with an example. @yonatanvainer

Comment: Thank you for your answer @yonatanvainer. I'm still little confuse what I should do in the delegate method. When I in my website click on this button it opens a new window in the web application. This window does not have an url. well the url is about:blank. And this site have some javascript and this javascript code does not work in iOS UIWebView.